# how can get this codeNumber in page.html?id=

Tags: cordova, dreamweaver

```
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inline="true">
                <li>
                <a href="#page" data-href="1">CTO-Tourism Org Office</a></li>
                <li>
                <a href="#page" data-href="2">HOSPITAL</a></li>
```

I am building a web index phone gap app in dreamweaver (2.3.0 phonegap) with web sql, well, if I want each listing in the web index has a page get data from db, of type page.html?id=5 eg if codeNumber of listing in db is 5...to eject data, how can get this codeNumber/id in page.html?

Comment: better this page.html be separate page or included in index.html? how get id in each case?

Answer (score 0):

try this piece of code in php
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){
            echo($_GET['id']);
        }

Comment: App is in html5/jQ mobi only not server side.html5/jQ: any body knows how get data-href value in link clicked, inside page.html(the page resulted from link clicked) this after this clicked???

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the difference between mobile devices and such, but I know of two ways of doing this (there are many more though).

### PHP

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
   $idFromUrl = $_GET['id'];
}
//now the id number is stored in variable $idFromUrl
```

### JavaScript

```
var split = location.search.replace('?', '').split('=')

//split[0] is your var name
//split[1] is your var value
```

Comment: in var split you get is only the query of url? any body knows how get data-href value in link clicked, from page.html(the href of link clicked) come after this clicked???

Comment: Your comment is pretty unclear. But you get the value by using the `split[1]` variable.

Comment: html5/jQ: any body knows how get data-href value in link clicked, inside page.html(the href of link clicked) this after this clicked???

Comment: html5/jQ: any body knows how get data-href value in link clicked, inside page.html(the page resulted from link clicked) this after this clicked???